# How to populate drop down list with all key values from local storage?

Tags: local-storage, html.dropdownlistfor

I have form with Name and Age input field in my html page. I insert the name and age and save the form using local storage.

Next I have a dropdown list and a input field and a display button.

I want to pre-populate the dropdown list will all names I have saved earlier.

Comment: do you have some code that is failing?

Comment: This is the save function i am using.function saveFunction() {
    
    var y = document.getElementById("savekey").value;

    var z = document.getElementById("savevalue").value;

    localStorage.setItem(y, z);


   
    var x = document.getElementById("displaykey");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = document.getElementById("savekey").value;
    x.add(option);

   

}

Answer (score 0):

I use this JavaScript code to build a drop-down on page load using jquery.

```
$(function() { // On page load
    $.each( localStorage.NAMES.split(","), function(i,val) { // val is the name
        $("#sbc").append("<option value='" + val + "'>"+ val +"</option>");
    });
});
```

The ID of the dropdown input is 'sbc'